# How to override magento customer forms

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to add a new field consultant name, in the magento signup form. I can simply do that by adding custom field using my module, and overriding these http://www.suncrescent.net/2012/07/magento-login-register-onepage/ template files.

But I don't want to override magento's core template files, instead I want a way using which I can add my templates and override that field only.

Do anyone knows any such way to simply add one field in magento signup form, without touching the core phtml files?

Please check and advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but the only way to do it is to copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` template to your theme and add a field there.